# How can I output my ajax result into a php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am storing my Ajax result into a div element. This is working well:

index.php:

```
<div id="result"></div>

function submit($form) {
    $.ajax('myajax.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            $('#result').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

myajax.php:

```
echo "12345";
```

I would like to do something like:

```
function submit($form) {
    $.ajax('myajax.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            $result = result;
        }
    });
}
```

Is it possible to output the result instead of the div into a PHP variable in this way?  Or, is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  PHP is *sending you* the value (from `myajax.php`).  Why do you need to tell the server-side code the value that *it just told you*?  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: It depends on what are you going to do with this php variable $result. What do you need this $result to do after that?

Comment: There's actually nothing wrong with this question.  It's a pretty standard Ajax usage question, not a "how do I take the long way to set a PHP variable" question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is completely possible, using the technique that you've presented.  In fact, the basic purpose of Ajax is to gather some information that can be acquired on the client, and send it to the backend server (PHP, in this case) asynchronously, without requiring the client page to be replaced.

Why might you want to do this?  Here are some commonly-used examples:

- getting form input from the user
- uploading file data asynchronously
- chat (although there are better options nowadays)
- collaborative presentation and design (also better options available)

Some less-than-common examples:

- using the client resources (CPU, memory) to perform distributed calculations (think: SETI@home, but via the browser)
- client health / online checks that send a unique token, such as a CSRF, back to the server on a timer
- use the browser as a lightweight, purpose-built web/API scraper/parser

Without exact details of the data that you're trying to send, it won't be possible to give a better example than what you've already provided.  Note that if you intend to serialize a form (for the data to transfer), you won't be able to store the data in a `<div>`; you'll have to either a) use a hidden form field, or b) manually serialize the elements that you want to send.

Your question shows that you're certainly thinking on the right track, and I'd love to know more about what you're actually trying to accomplish to give a more thorough answer.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. In myajax.php I am simply generating a number that I want to use multiple times on index.php